# Multilevel future states with lazy loading is not working

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, lazy-loading

I want to use multilevel routing with future states in UI Router.

Here is what I have tried:

Level 0 - state: account.**

Level 2 - state: account.profile.**

```
const accountState = {
name: 'account',
url: '/account',
template: '<ui-view />'
}

const accountFutureState = {
name: 'account.**',
url: '/account',
loadChildren: () =>
    import('account/account.js').then(mod => {
      return mod.AccountModule;
    })
}
const profileState = {
name: 'account.profile',
url: '/profile',
template: '<ui-view />'
}

const profileFutureState = {
name: 'account.profile.**',
url: '/profile',
loadChildren: () =>
    import('account/profile.js').then(mod => {
      return mod.ProfileModule;
    })
}
```

When I tried this, it shows the following output in console and routes are not working.

```
stateMatcher.find: Found multiple matches for account.profile.details using glob:  (2) ["account.**", "account.profile.**"]
```